# Using homotopy to show that vector fields vanish on a point of the disc

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, manifolds

Am reading Essential Topology by Martin Crossley.

On page 113 there is a proof that if you stir a cup of coffee a point on the surface has to be stationary.

The whole proof makes sense to me except one part.

When we define

$$v: D^2 \to R^2$$

$$g: S^1\to S^1     $$

$$ g(x,y)=-v/|v|   $$

and then conclude by contradiction that $v(x,y)$ is zero somewhere, yet on the unit circle and not on the unit disc.

In particular he says that:

**...thinking of $(x,y) \in S^1$ as a point on the boundary of $D^2$** when defining $g$.

Aren't we supposed to show that $v$ is zero somewhere on $D^2$ and not only $S^1$?

The question here is about the domain of $g$ and not its image. Which one is the domain of $g$,  $D^2$ or $S^1$?

Comment: What is $v\phantom{}$?

Comment: the vector field,  $v: D^2 \to R^2$

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your question properly. Can you give more information about what your finding are doing and so on.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but you should notice that the function -v/|v| takes points everywhere on the disk to the boundary.

Comment: Yes correct. But the question is about the domain of $g$ and not the image. Which one is the domain of $g$,  $D^2$ or $S^1$?

Comment: It's a map defined on all of $D^2$ but in this argument you only care about it on $S^1$. The vector field being nowhere zero is an important assumption you should have included